# How can I set and split a dataframe value in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have been working on a huge .csv dataset which I have to string split every row of it in order to make some calculations on them later. What I am trying to do basically is I am trying to split the default string which is in another csv dataframe and then export it to another csv file which I will make some similarity tests on. Here is my current code:

```
def preprocess(text):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(text) if word.lower() not in stop and not word.isdigit()]

df['Product'] = df['Product'].apply(preprocess)
df['Issue'] = df['Issue'].apply(preprocess)
df['Company'] = df['Company'].apply(preprocess)

df['Product'] = df['Product'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')
df['Issue'] = df['Issue'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')
df['Company'] = df['Company'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')

df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.split()
df['Issue'] = df['Issue'].str.split()
df['Company'] = df['Company'] .str.split()
```

This is what I've been trying to do but it just puts the data in more "" so when I am doing a similarity test between words it shows similarity even if it isn't similar(because it also tests ""). I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the columns as a unit.

```py
    df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.split()
    df['Issue']   = df['Issue'].str.split()
    df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.split()
```

Aggregate operations are our friends. :)

Comment: Oh, really? So I have been complicating my own code for no reason at all? I am going to try it right now thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[['Product', 'Issue', 'Company']] = df[['Product', 'Issue', 'Company']].apply(lambda s: s.str.split())` ;)

Comment: The problem is different now I edited my question please check it.

Comment: The middle section can be improved. Instead of 
`df['Product'] = df['Product'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')` try `df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.join(' ')`